# jQuery Mobile Tabs showing content of all tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to set up a tabbed navigation bar but it's not hiding the content from the other tabs.

On a similar note, creating a new page doesn't work in the same way. It shows the content of the other page as if I was writing it normally.

```
<!-- Chat Display and Tabs -->
   <div id="tabs" data-role="tabs">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#globalChat" data-ajax="false">Global Chat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#allyChat" data-ajax="false">Alliance Chat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#privateChat" data-ajax="false">Private Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="#globalChat" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        <div id="incomingMessages" name="incomingMessages" class="msgContainerDiv" ></div> <!-- Global Chat Display -->
      </div>
      <div id="#allyChat" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        <div id="incomingAMessages" name="incomingMessages" class="msgContainerDiv" ></div> <!-- Global Chat Display -->
      </div>
      <div id="#privateChat" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        <div id="incomingPMessages" name="incomingMessages" class="msgContainerDiv" ></div> <!-- Global Chat Display -->
      </div>
   </div>
```

Head Tag:

```
<head>
<title>Mod Panel</title>
<meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=utf-8>

<meta name=viewport content=width=device-width>
<meta name=viewport content=initial-scale=1.0>
<meta name=viewport content=user-scalable=no>

<meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes>  
<meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<link href="css/toastr.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/md5.js"></script>
 <script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script src="js/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="js/dateFormat.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.modpanel.js"></script>
<script src="js/blacklist.js"></script>
</head>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NA3nd2QaRVHW063kdP8z?p=preview)

Comment: Do create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) in the future. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the `id`s of your `#globalChat`, `#allyChat` and `#privateChat` divs. When setting an id, the hash (`#`) shouldn't be prepended to the name, only when referring to the id is the hash prepended.

For instance:

```
<div id="#globalChat" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
```

should be

```
<div id="globalChat" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
```

in order to be referred to by

```
<a href="#globalChat" data-ajax="false">Global Chat</a>
```

setting `id='#globalChat` means you need to reference `##globalChat` (I'm not even sure if this will work).

I've forked [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4xgwjiMXoVvHg7uSHfxy?p=preview) and the tabs work fine with the updated ids.

[image: aliance chat]
[image: global chat]

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I probably copy and pasted the ids and didn't even think about it. But, I made the changes and now the tabs will pan down to the appropriate spot. But they are still not hiding the other tabbed content.

Comment: Is my plunker working for you? Because it hides the tabbed content for me.

Comment: The plunker does indeed work. But I don't see what is different between it and my code now that I removed the hashmarks from the div ids. EDIT: It looks, to me, like the versions of jquery and jqm in the plunker are different from mine.

Comment: Frankly, without looking at your full code and comparing the differences, I can't tell either. Though one possibility is differing jQuery versions. [This discussion](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-exception-jquery-ui-tabs-mismatching-fragment-identifier-5-2-2010) seems to suggest something along those lines

Comment: The problem is, if I use a higher version of jqm it breaks my design. Is this version incompatible with all the tab features or something? I'm pretty new to jqm, and jquery in general.

Comment: I doubt it. Just make sure your jQuery version matches your jQuery Mobile one in the sense both are compatible. For instance, jqm `Version 1.4.5` is meant to be used with `jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1`

Comment: I'm fairly sure my versions are compatible. So I don't know why it's not working right for me.

Comment: I suggest you leave this question open for the time being, see if anyone more experienced than us can shed light on the issue.